# Implementing ACL in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

My team have been working on implementing reports using Crystal Reports 2008. We are faced with the following problem:

We need to be able to organize the reports into groups (representing the various departments in our workplace). The groups will have access to only the reports which they are authorized to. Is there any way to define the groups and associate the reports to the groups. Is this something that Crystal Reports 2008 provides out of the box?

Also, can additional custom metadata (like attributes) be associated to the reports?

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: This should probably be in ServerFault but my understanding is that Crystal Reports is capable of this out of the box - although I could be wrong. I can check with my work colleagues (some of them install CR2008 and subsequent training)

Comment: One of my colleagues has replied below - hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. we are now using CR 2008. We are implementing the above requirement as follows: Creating a group and then authorizing the groups to selected reports. Its pretty neat. We are also programatically retrieving the reports using the Crystal Reports API. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Crystal Reports Server 2008 V1 in order to achieve this.

http://www.crystalreports.co.uk/crystal-reports-server/

Hope this helps.

Steve